# ObservableCollection loses its collection

Tags: c#, wpf, unity-container, prism, prism-5

Using WPF with Prism and Unity -

I have a strange defect where an ObservableCollection is losing its collection.

I’ve added a real backing field to see if there was something funny happening with the automatic property.

I’ve added a CollectionChanged event handler on the field that only fires when I’m expecting it.

I’m using service locator to retrieve the instance so I thought maybe I was getting a different instance, but the other properties and fields have the expected values from a previous access.

Storing the ViewModel -

```
this.Container.RegisterInstance(
new ShellViewModel(), new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

Retrieving it -

```
return App.getUnityContainer().Resolve<ShellViewModel>();
```

The ObservableCollection Field -

```
private readonly ObservableCollection<BusinessProcessViewModel> openBusinessProcesses =  
new ObservableCollection<BusinessProcessViewModel>();
```

ObservableCollection Property -

```
public ObservableCollection<BusinessProcessViewModel> OpenBusinessProcesses  
 { get { return openBusinessProcesses; } }
```

ObservableCollection Field Event Handler -

```
    private void AttachEventHandlers()
    {
        openBusinessProcesses.CollectionChanged += openBusinessProcesses_CollectionChanged;
    }

    void openBusinessProcesses_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        logger.Info(String.Format("OpenBusinessProcess collection changed. Action: {0}, Added: {1}, Removed: {2}", e.Action, e.NewItems, e.OldItems));
    }
```

Comment: By 'losing its collection' do you mean the collection becomes empty? Also a reliable way to determine if the instance is the same: check for `object.GetHashCode()` value. The value should be the same each time you access the instance, or else you have different instances.

Comment: Yes, the collection becomes empty.   
Thanks for the HashCode reminder. It was not the same instance.

Comment: @AlekseyShubin The value returned by `GetHashCode` is not unique. It's certainly possible that two (or more) separate instances may have the same hash code. The [`Object.ReferenceEquals`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method should be used to check whether two instances are "the same".

Comment: @StevenRands definitely agree if you are checking instances in a code. But in case of debugging you probably doesn't even have references to both objects simultaneously (as in the author's case), so you cannot use `ReferenceEquals`. `GetHashCode` is a good alternative in my opinion, though it does not give 100% confidence, but something around 99.9% is fine too (again, for debugging purposes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Aleksey. You got me on the right track.

I forgot I had added auto-wiring in the view, so I had two instances of the view model.

This is the part I removed from the xaml markup -

```
viewModel:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
```

Update for clarity -
The ObservableCollection was NOT being emptied. The autowiring in the view, plus the explicit model creation resulted in two instances of the view model.

Comment: This isn't an answer.

Comment: Yes, it is an answer. There were two instances of the view model; the ObservableCollection was not really being emptied.